# VBA marking cells Based on keywords

Tags: excel, vba, colors, cell

I have defined a range which is filled with color based on the cell text. In the first example it searches the word "Auto" and marks the cell red. Where I get stuck is to extent the "if" command such as that the search criteria carries onto the column E (however stays at the same row as the word " Auto" states) looks after the word "Mortgage" and marks it red. Then it moves further the column up and marks the values red that are under 4yr, 6yr,7yr. The next step would be the same with the word "preferred". For simplicity I have included a picture. It seems to be a bit tricky and a hint would be appreciated.

[image]

```
 Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
 Dim cell As Range

 For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A100")
     If cell.Value = "Auto" Then
     cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed

     ElseIf cell.Value = "Mutti" Then
     cell.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't conditional formatting be easier? Or do I miss something?

Comment: Conditional formatting sounds what I am looking for. Could I get a simple example?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://exceljet.net/conditional-formatting-with-formulas) or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enter-and-format-data-fef13169-0a84-4b92-a5ab-d856b0d7c1f7#ID0EAABAAA=Conditional_formatting)

Comment: Allow me to look for some VBA examples and apply it to my case. If i get stuck somewhere I will try to look for help here. Thnk you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
Sub Schaltfläche2_Klicken()
 Dim cell As Range

 For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A100")
    If cell.Value = "Auto" Then
        Range("A" & cell.Row, "E" & cell.Row, "G" & cell.Row, "I" & cell.Row, "K" & cell.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf cell.Value = "Mutti" Then
        Range("A" & cell.Row, "E" & cell.Row, "G" & cell.Row, "I" & cell.Row, "K" & cell.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, the code runs into an error. Secondly, the code marks the rows B,C and D as well.